# Getting error in echoing value of POST

Tags: php

This is what my code, problem with all `<input>` tag, can any one tell me is this the correct way to integrate HTML and PHP

```
<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">Email Address:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left">

<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST["email"]); ?>"     class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs"></div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">
```

Comment: what's error or issue you getting from this code ?

Comment: Please try and create a succinct title explaining the problem instead of just code.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\wamp\www\Saravanan\PHP\signup_and_login_with_php\signup.php on line 69 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0031391424{main}( )..\signup.php:0 " class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs">

Comment: Hey  andyb, i am trying to ask through statement but its not accepting whatever i type.

Comment: you have to check if post variables exist with isset.

Comment: Hi Suhel Meman, thanks for your effort, but this too i am getting same error.

Comment: post ur code from line no.69 where u get an error

Answer (score 2):

you need to make sure that `$_POST["email"]` is set before use for that you can use `isset()` like

```
<?php if(isset($_POST["email"])) { echo strip_tags($_POST["email"]); }else{echo 'default' ;} ?>
```

Comment: i do, additionally i chk group of values with db. please see this if(isset($_POST["submitted"]) && $_POST["submitted"] == "yes")

Comment: yes its fine .. you can do like this but make sure that you always first check that element is set before checking with specific value like you did in comment

Comment: error (Notice: Undefined index: firstname) means username was not set when you tried to use it. So you still dont check all variables.

Comment: so should i check with my table?

Comment: @user2219660  well i am sure you know about how [$_POST super global works](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php), yes you need to check all POST that they are set before use .. you can also check them with database but checking first that those are set is i think should be done first

Comment: it is simple. Always use : if(isset($_POST['some_post_variable'])){ now do operation with $_POST['some_post_variable']}

Answer (score 0):

use `ternary operator` to display default value for each `input` instead

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])?strip_tags($_POST['email']):''; ?>" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs"></div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">
```

same for `firstname`

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['firstname'])?strip_tags($_POST['firstname']):''; ?>" >
```

Comment: that is not the problem, he is not checking if POST['email'] exist.

Comment: Hi please look at it, <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST['firstname']); ?>" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs">

Comment: you need to check for all variables you get with post that they exist before you can use it. Same goes for email,firstname ...

Comment: Instead of "submitted" in if(isset($_POST["submitted"]) && $_POST["submitted"] == "yes") should i use all variable inside condition?

Comment: if default value will be empty string, you dont need ternary operator, default value will be empty anyway in case if is not executed.